# How would I go about making a union of nested structs/unions compatible with 64-bit conventions in C?

Tags: c, struct, alignment

So, this could be a tricky one, but here goes. I'm working on an old C project, called PMML, the practical music macro language. It's a programming language for midi from the late 90's. I have the code available on github, (https://github.com/arfy8820/pmml), originally written by another author.
I've been a C dabbler for years, but this code's stretching my (admittedly limited) skill set.
First off, this code seems to be written in K&R style! Makes it hard to figure out what functions have prototypes. The original author used some preprocessor magic to adapt the code to both non-ansi and ansi C.

But now, to the main event. I've managed to get the code to the point where it compiles on both 32 and 64-bit systems, however, on a 64-bit system, such as my Apple M1 mac, which has no way to run code as 32-bit, pmml segfaults as soon as it tries to do anything other than display help.
Yes, I can compile as 32-bit on every other system/VM I've tried, but I'd love to get this running natively on my mac, too.

I believe I've isolated the issue to it's main data structure, which is a union of several different types. As stated in pmml.h:

```
/* 
 * Object - the data type of the PMML
 *   Each macro is associated with an object.
 *   Each array element is an object.
 *   Each object occupies 8 bytes.
 */
```

It's that last rule, each object is 8 bytes, that breaks under 64-bit conditions. Here's my understanding of how this union works.

First, some things to know from earlier in pmml.h.

```
/********************************************************************
 * Definition of byte order
 ********************************************************************/
#ifndef PMML_BIG_ENDIAN
#  ifdef PMML_LITTLE_ENDIAN
#    define PMML_BIG_ENDIAN  0
#  else
#    if defined(mc68000) || defined(sparc) || defined(MIPSEB)
#      define PMML_BIG_ENDIAN  1
#    else
#      if defined(i386) || defined(__x86_64__) || defined(__arm64) || defined(MIPSEL) || defined(alpha)
#        define PMML_BIG_ENDIAN  0
#      else
         ... Either PMML_BIG_ENDIAN or PMML_LITTLE_ENDIAN must be defined.
#      endif
#    endif
#  endif
#endif
```

Yeah, this codes trying to run in a lot of places!

Useful typedefs to know.

```
typedef unsigned char  uchar;
typedef int   PmmlInt;
typedef double PmmlFloat;
```

Now, for the union.

```
typedef union object {
    struct {
#if PMML_BIG_ENDIAN
    unsigned short  type;   /* O_XXX */
    short  pad1;
    short  pad2;
    short  pad3;
#else
    short  pad1;
    short  pad2;
    short  pad3;
    unsigned short  type;   /* O_XXX */
#endif
    } _t; // 4 shhorts, 8 bytes on both 32 and 64-bit
    Rational  r; // Rational is defined as 4 shorts, so again, 8 bytes regardless of bit-width

PmmlFloat  fpval;       /* for O_FLOAT */ 
// PmmlFloat is a double, so again, 8 bytes.
```

Now, the fun starts.

```
    struct {
#if PMML_BIG_ENDIAN
    long   pad; // only for big endian systems, 4 bytes.
#endif
    union object_data {
        PmmlInt  val;   /* for O_INT */
        char   *str;    /* for O_STRING */
        struct array  *ap;  /* for O_ARRAY */
        struct token  *tp;  /* for O_STOKENS or O_WTOKENS */
    } _u;
    } _d;
```

Here, I think, is the key of this union. There must be a reason for big-endian systems to have that long pad at the start of the structure. To me, it indicates that the nested union here is expected to take up 4 bytes. We're still inside the main Object union. Where the 8-byte rule breaks are the pointers. on 32-bit systems, everything is fine, and the int and 3 pointers take up the same space. however, on 64-bit? that asumption breaks.

So, thoughts I had to proceed.

- Could I simply pad everything in the union if the code is running on a 64-bit arch, to say, 12 or 16 bytes?
- I've briefly played with just turning everything into structs, but that didn't quite work either.

Sorry for the length, but I hope this is enough info to help us work out what could be done here.

Thanks!
arfy

Comment: "*where it's expecting 4 bytes,*". Who is doing the expecting and why? You could be right but you have made an assertion there without explaining adequately how you reached it. So it would be good to clarify before we head down the wrong path based on an incorrect premise.

Comment: You can't have 32-bit pointers on 64-bit applications. Perhaps you should build your program in 32-bit mode?

Comment: Perhaps use the macro [`offsetof()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19p3)?

Comment: On a 64-bit system, the pointers will be 8 bytes each.  That violates the the 4-byte requirement.  The pad member is puzzling though.  It should be omitted and then the structure will be 8-bytes.  What type are you using for `PmmlInt`?  Using 64-bit `long` might be best, but beware format strings.  Also, beware what the MIDI specification requires.

Comment: Hi all. Updated my original question with more details, hopefully to clarify things.